# Using camera device (WebRTC API) in UC android browser

Tags: javascript, camera, webrtc, uc-browser

we are developing web application which should use camera device (WebRTC standard) for reading QR codes and we are serious issue in UC Android browser. 
Here is example of our app https://www.publicstaticvoidmain.cz/qr/

It works well in most common browsers, but we struggling with UC Android Browser (mini as well) support.

We detected following issues with no solution yet. 
Do you have any related experience with UC browser?

1) Changing camera resolution? It seems that video from camera is provided with some default resolution 640 x 480
We are using

`navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(options, succesCallback, errorCallback)` or `navigator.getUserMedia(options, succesCallback, errorCallback)` from WebRTC API but none of configuration options bellow are working:(

```
video: {            
   width: { min: 360, ideal: 1280, max: 1920 },
   height: { min: 240, ideal: 720, max: 1080 },
}

video: {            
   width: 1280,
   height: 720
}
```

2) Camera auto-focus doesn't work properly. In other browsers (also in UC desktop browser) is auto-focus working.

3) Video preview doesn't fit video tag size, video fit size only horizontally?

4) Mobile is "beeping" during capturing images from video stream for processing in QR code library.

Also UC Android Browser crash during periodic capturing of images from camera. It seems that it depends on how often is taken the picture from video stream for analyzing QR code.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

As  per caniuse **uc browser** doesn't support webrtc hence it's not working
http://caniuse.com/#feat=rtcpeerconnection

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but you mentioned  WebRTC Peer-to-peer which is slightly different thing. We are using http://caniuse.com/#search=getUserMedia and it souhld ne supported in UC Android browser.

Comment: Hmmm. It says partial support/ support older version